# Google maps markers show on android device but not on emulator

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout

Attempting to add a marker to a google maps fragment in android studio. Code runs successfully displaying the marker on the map when the code is run on android device however when attempting to run on an emulator the markers never show up

```
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(point.getLat(), point.getLongi()))
                .title("Point: " +point.getID())
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN))
        );
        marker.setSnippet("Latitude: " + point.getLat() + "\nLongitude: " + point.getLongi() + "\nDescription: " + point.getDesc() + "\nLight at " + point.getTime() + " : " + point.getLight());
        marker.setTag(point.getID());
        markers.add(marker);
        marker.setVisible(true);
```

Expected: marker to show itself on the map
Actual: no marker shown

For some reason this marker does show though:

```
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
            .title("Hello world"));
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

>

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"/>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="382dp"
    map:layout_anchor="@+id/include"
    map:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Fixed, am going to leave this as proof of my shame, the marker was on the map but the emulator was set to N. America. In my stupidity i did not zoom out and see this, it was never broken in the first place**

Comment: does the map show on the device  ?

Comment: Yes and the second marker code I put just not the first. All data added correctly and creates marker successfully

Comment: are the device map and emulator map show the same area ? no gps involved ?

Comment: Yep, just adds a marker. My only thought is android device is api 24 but emulator api 28 but dont see how that would change anything

Comment: Tested on api 24 emulator and same problem

Comment: this is weird !

Comment: Please add a screenshot to your post.